# actionscript 3 swapping movieclips sequentially

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I'm a relatively new user of actionscript 3 and things have been going along pretty well, but I am having difficulty finding a way to accomplish swapping movieclips in a sequential order based on their name. For example, I have a bunch of movieclips named "Guy 1", "Guy 2", "Guy 3", etc. and I am wondering what I should do to make them swap out sequentially on the clicking of a button.

I understand that I can use the removeChild and addChild functions, but I don't know how to change which children to remove and add so that each time the button is pressed, it increases by one. I am hoping to do it this way as I have at least 32 of these movieclips and I might want to add more, so I see it as the easiest way work with so many without having to manually make the button check individually for each movieclip. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask good questions. In this particular case you should present a code sample demonstrating your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your `MovieClips` into array and hold current position.

```
function showNext():void{
  removeChild(arrayOfClips[currentPosition]);

  if(currentPosition == arrayOfClips.length -1){
    currentPosition = 0;
  }else{
    currentPosition++;
  }

  addChild(arrayOfClips[currentPosition]);
}
```